# Qt: create custom QTextCursor select

Tags: c++, qt

So, the method `select(SelectionType)` in the class `QTextCursor` only has 4 possible parameters.

```
QTextCursor::Document
QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor
QTextCursor::LineUnderCursor
QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor
```

Is it possible to create custom selectiontypes? Say if I want to select the text from position 5 to 9. Thanks!

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`setPosition`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#setPosition) like this:

```
cursor.setPosition(5);
cursor.setPosition(9, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
```

This will set the cursor's Anchor to 5 and its Position to 9. The selection is the text between anchor and position.